# python - pass a argument expecting function object

Tags: python

I am using exoredis, a key-value store that works great as a cache.
It has a method `get_or_set` that sets the value of the key if it doesn't exist already.

```
exoredis.get_or_set('my_new_key', 'my new value')
```

Here, `my new value` can also be a callable that returns a string like:

```
exoredis.get_or_set('some-timestamp-key', datetime.datetime.now)
```

In my case, my callable needs to accept one argument "`pk`":

```
def get_gender(pk):
    return Users.objects.filter(pk=pk).gender
```

---

How do I pass this function as a callable?
This gives me a `TypeError` saying my function expects one argument. (In the event that it is executed)

```
pk = request.user.id
print exoredis.get_or_set("gender:%s"%pk, get_gender)
```

`TypeError: get_gender() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

---

This executes the function each time:

```
pk = request.user.id
print exoredis.get_or_set("gender:%s"%pk, get_gender(pk))
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Can you post the complete Traceback?

Comment: Do you want `get_gender` to be called with the current value of `pk` when it's eventually called? **Or** do you want it to be called with the value that `pk` had when you passed it to `exoredis.get_or_set`?

Comment: I have refactored the question. Hope it makes things clear-er now.

Comment: take a look at `functools.partial`.

Comment: John's answer shows you how to pass `get_gender` to `exoredis.get_or_set` so that when `get_gender` _is_ eventually called it will be called with the current value that `pk` has. But the other option is that when `get_gender` is eventually called it will use the _old_ value that `pk` had when you originally passed `get_gender` to `exoredis.get_or_set`. Would you like to see code for that second option?

Comment: In my case `pk` won't change. But, sure, I would love that!

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted, seems a pretty reasonable query to me. :/

Comment: Ok. I've posted an answer with some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to wrap the one-argument function in a zero-argument function, and then pass that zero-arg function to the function that wants a zero-arg function.

As I mentioned in the comments there are two options here:
1) When the wrapped function is eventually called it's called with the current value of its parameter.
2) When the wrapped function is eventually called it's called with the old value that its parameter had when it got wrapped.

The code below illustrates both options.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

def myfunc(s):
    return 'myfunc ' + s

s = 'hello'
a = Test(lambda: myfunc(s))
s = 'bye'
print(a.f())

s = 'hello'
a = Test(lambda s=s: myfunc(s))
s = 'bye'
print(a.f())
```

**output**

```
myfunc bye
myfunc hello
```

The "trick" used in the second option is to set the parameter as a default argument, since default arguments are evaluated when the function definition is executed, that is, when the function is created.

Technically, `lambda s=s: myfunc(s)` is *really* a one-arg function, but we can call it with zero args and it will use the supplied default value for its argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
pk = request.user.id
print exoredis.get_or_set("gender:%s"%pk, lambda: get_gender(pk))
```

Pass in a lambda function that takes no arguments. This will ensure `get_gender` is called later rather than immediately.

Comment: This works but looks hacky, is there a more *Pythonic* way?

Comment: It is a Pythonic way, another alternative is `functools.partial`.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: It's a fairly common Python idiom; OTOH, Guido is not a big fan of lambda. You _could_ use a named function instead of the `lambda`, eg. `def get_user_gender(): return get_gender(request.user.id)`, then pass `get_user_gender` to `exoredis.get_or_set`, but using a lambda is obviously more compact, and there's no need to create a named function if you aren't going to reference it multiple times, IMHO.